# How to use webpack for compiling LESS files only

Tags: webpack

I want to use webpack for compiling only LESS files. I have a project that already bundles js files with browserify and I only need webpack to compile LESS because webpack provides a superior resolution algorithm for LESS.

I tried this `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: 'less-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

When I run `webpack-cli -w`, I get this error:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'xxxx'
```

Comment: go to this website [https://webpack.jakoblind.no/](https://webpack.jakoblind.no/) and build your webpack.config.js

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't enough though. I had to change config.entry to point to the LESS file. Also, I had to use the mini-css-extract-plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

Comment: @ZoltanKochan Could you please add an actual answer with code?